# Django REST AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, django, unicode, django-rest-framework

I'm stuck with this problem:

views.py:

```
class PatientList(generics.ListAPIView):
    """Patient List Information"""
    queryset = Patient.status_objects.active()
    serializer_class = PatientListSerializer
    filter_class = PatientFilter
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter, )
    paginate_by = 10
```

serializers.py:

```
class PatientListSerializer( serializers.ModelSerializer ):
    district = DistrictSerializer()
    country = CountrySerializer()
    region = RegionSerializer()
    division = DivisionSerializer()

    sex = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_sex_friendly_name')

    def get_sex_friendly_name(self,obj):
        return obj.sex_friendly_name

    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = ('id','temporary_id','first_name','surname','birthdate','sex',
                   'address_1','address_2','address_3','district','country','region','division'
                   ,'phone','mobile','email','postcode',
                   'photo','privacy','nickname',
                 )
```

filters.py:

```
class PatientFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    first_name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_type='icontains')
    surname = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_type='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = ('id','temporary_id','first_name','surname','birthdate','sex',
                  'address_1','address_2','address_3','district','country','region','division'
                  ,'phone','mobile','email','postcode',
                  'photo','privacy','nickname',
                )
        order_by = ( 'nickname', 'first_name', 'surname', 'id', 'temporary_id','sex','country','division', )
```

when I hit the view, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 77, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 399, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 396, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 402, in get
    return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 96, in list
    return Response(serializer.data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 507, in data
    self._data = self.to_native(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 309, in to_native
    value = field.field_to_native(obj, field_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 350, in field_to_native
    return [self.to_native(item) for item in value.all()]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 309, in to_native
    value = field.field_to_native(obj, field_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 362, in field_to_native
    return self.to_native(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 309, in to_native
    value = field.field_to_native(obj, field_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 177, in field_to_native
    value = get_component(value, component)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 56, in get_component
    val = getattr(obj, attr_name)
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'id'
```

What are the possible reasons it may happen?

Comment: The view has a 'traceback as text' link (or words to that effect). Please follow that link and include the full traceback in your question.

Comment: Please add the tag django-rest-framework to your question. It makes it easier for other people to help you, to get helped and is a tribute to the software package you're using.

Comment: I've added the tag django-rest-framework @cezar

Comment: I've added the full traceback, but it looks creepy.

Comment: The error reports that the object has no attribute 'id'. Does your model `Patient` has the attribute 'id'? Try to remove 'id' from `fields` in the serializers and from `fields` and `order_by` in the filters. What happens then?

Comment: @All, I got rid of this problem by editing PatientListSerializer. I did the following:     
`district = DistrictSerializer(many=False)
country = CountrySerializer(many=False)
region = RegionSerializer(many=False)
division = DivisionSerializer(many=False)`
Theoretically I'm unable to explain this solution. If anyone can explain why this solution works I shall appreciate. TIA